# regression analysis, time series analysis, or glmm?

Tags: regression, time-series, anova, repeated-measures, glmm

I have a sample of individuals for each of two treatments measured across several days (different individuals for each treatment, but the same individuals within treatment across days). The pattern I see in all my dependent measures is that comparisons across both days and treatment appear significantly different - results for both treatments increase across days, but not linearly, and not at the same time (one treatment rises several days later than the other). These are not drug data, but I suspect that the statistics would be similar to those used in such studies.

I'm wondering what the best type of analysis might be for this sort of data (a statistical test that would account for both days and treatment, as I suspect these are both significantly different). The figure shows mean +/- SD for one such dataset.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this an example of [Panel data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel_data)? You could start by writing the statistical model for results as a function of time and individual, and deciding which coefficients will be common accross individuals and which will differ